# Vue use Plugin in function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

im relative new to Vue.js but now i stuck on a maybe stupid simple problem.

I have two files, one for the routes and one for a plugin.

auth.js

```
export default {
    install: (Vue, options) => {

        Vue.prototype.$auth = {

            login: (email, password) => {
                ...
            }
        };
    }
};
```

and the router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import auth from '../auth'

Vue.use(auth);
Vue.use(Router);


const router = new Router({
    ...

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'index',
            component: function(resolve) {
                require(['../../components/list/index.vue'], resolve)
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/admin',
            name: 'adm',
            component: function(resolve) {
                require(['../../components/admin/event.vue'], resolve)
            },
            beforeEnter: guardRoute
        }

    ]
});

function guardRoute (to, from, next) {
    console.log('?');
}

export default router;
```

Now in the guardRoute function i want to call the plugin, but i don't know how. I tried something like console.log(auth) but there is only the install() function but not the $auth object. I also tried console.log(Vue) or console.log(router) but i'm not able to call/find the login()-function or the $auth object from the plugin in the console output. So what am i doing wrong? Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auth plugin is adding the `$auth` object to the `Vue.prototype`. So, you need to first get a reference to the related Vue instance in the `beforeEnter` navigation guard.

To do that, you'll need to pass a callback to the `next` parameter. The Vue instance is the first parameter in the callback:

```
function guardRoute(to, from, next) {
  next(vm => vm.$auth.login('email', 'password'));
}
```

[Here's the documentation on the navigation guards.](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. But now i get the following error: [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Comment: That would most likely be caused by a misconfigured Vue component definition. Are you pulling in the component definitions correctly?

Comment: ah, let me call you my hero of the day. i found the problem. thanks man